# Unreal Engine 5 project won't build Could not spawn process \Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, unreal-engine5

I've been trying to follow the [Programming Quick Start](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/CPPProgrammingQuickStart/) Guide but translating the instructions into UE5 instead of 4. I am trying to use Visual Studio 2022 after it defaulted to 2019. I had no issues. The engine is stored on my F: drive while my projects are stored on my G: drive. Not sure what I changed along the process but before the only problem was that the class would not spawn a cube mesh with the FloatingActor class, but if I assigned it to a mesh it would work fine. Now it won't compile?
The error that pops up is "Could not spawn process C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe. Error: 267"
Not sure if it is because I am trying to use VS2022 and need to change that in a setting somewhere?

I tried changing the compiler version in Project Settings > Platforms > Windows > Compiler Version to Visual Studio 2022, and expected the error to go away since it mentions Visual Studio 2019, but obviously it did not help.

Comment: Is this a clean build? Have you tried deleting the build folder and rebuilding / using the IDE's clean build action?

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install of UE5 an it fixed the issue. Might have had something to do with changing the drive letter of where the projects had been stored, even though I made a new project after and it still didn't work. Also did a fresh install of VS2019 and have been trying to use that instead.